# Halmos on Definability and Luzin on Division by 0

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, arithmetic, definition

For a successful introduction of a new symbol (e.g. '$\emptyset$') into a mathematical discourse it is necessary and sufficient that the symbol refer to something (e.g. Existence + Specification in ZF) and to nothing else (e.g. Extensionality). I learned of this notion of definability from Halmos (1960).

Luzin (1961) has an introductory section (§8) explaining why division by $0$ isn't allowed. His argument seems new to me so I just want to ask whether I understood it properly. He doesn't say this explicitly, but it seems that he relies on the notion of definability described above. Consider:

$$a\over 0 \tag 1$$

We know that $(1)$ denotes the *unique* number $b$ s.t. $b \cdot 0 = a$. Now, either $a=0$ or $a \ne 0$.

1. If $a = 0$, then according to that definition, $(1)$ denotes the unique number $b$ that satisfies the equation $b \cdot 0 = 0$. But *all* numbers satisfy that equation, so while there *is* such a number $b$, there is no *unique* root of that equation, so by the definition of definability, $(1)$ fails to denote a number when $a =0$.
2. If $a \ne 0$, then according to that same definition, $(1)$ denotes the unique number $b$ that satisfies the equation $b \cdot0 =a$, where $a$ by hypothesis differs from $0$. But *no* $b$ different from $0$ satisfies that equation, so by the definition of definability, $(1)$ fails to denote a number when $a \ne 0$.

Since in both cases $(1)$ fails to denote a unique number, $(1)$ is said to be ill-defined. That's my reconstruction of Luzin's argument - is it entirely correct?

### References

- Halmos, P. (1960) *Naive Set Theory*.
- Luzin, N.N. (1961) *Differential Calculus*.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Whether the reconstruction of the argument is correct. Thank you for the edit.

Comment: That argument is (as far as I know) the standard explanation for why division by 0 isn't allowed. I am curious that you describe this as "new to you".  Is there some other explanation that you are more familiar with?

Comment: @mweiss All of mathematics is new to me, so that probably was a rather misleading thing to say. I have heard people say that it's meaningless, by the definition of rational numbers: a rational number is an expression of form $a / b$ where $b \ne 0$. Therefore, $x / 0$ is not a rational number for any $x$. As you know, there are many such explanations. Luzin's argument is the first one that I feel satisfactorily addresses the question.

Comment: Anybody who's given you that explanation ("It's meaningless by definition") is dodging the issue. The question is, *why is it defined that way?*  Definitions are instrumental; any time you see a definition with a clause in it excluding some case (like a stipulation that $b \neq 0$ it usually signals that something goes wrong in that case.

Comment: @mweiss I'll be more sensitive to such explanations now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your construction is correct.

If $\dfrac{a}{0}$ = c, then $a = 0 \cdot c$. But $0\cdot c = 0$. Hence, if $a$ is not equal to $0$, no value of c can make the statement $a = 0\cdot c$ true, while if $a = 0$, every value of $c$ will make the statement true.

Thus, $\dfrac{a}{0}$ either has *no* value or is *indefinite* in value.